# Build Angular 2 App in Jenkins

Tags: angular, jenkins

I'm trying to build a sample angular 2 app similar to this:
https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart.

I have cloned this project into my repository, but besides installing node on Jenkins, I'm unsure of what else to modify in order for the build to be successful. Are there any dependencies I need to install for this to work?

The only script I'm running is npm install, and the job is still failing.

This is the console results:

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on r008p8p0c TPC (bxp2-prod linuxCleanUp) in workspace /bxp/jen/slave99/workspace/wmz-angular
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url https://git.url # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://git.url
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials git
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress https://git.url +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/feature/ruth-3-6-17^{commit} # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/feature/ruth-3-6-17^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 61164adcfa55d6ee096b6969b8c043187ae1fa88 (refs/remotes/origin/feature/ruth-3-6-17)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f 61164adcfa55d6ee096b6969b8c043187ae1fa88
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list 61164adcfa55d6ee096b6969b8c043187ae1fa88 # timeout=10
[wmz-angular] $ /bxp/jen/slave99/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_0.12.9_v8/bin/node /tmp/hudson1546788266894720709.js
/tmp/hudson1546788266894720709.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { npm install
                                                                  ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
Build step 'Execute NodeJS script' marked build as failure
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: You got any error message while your job fails?

Comment: Did you configured your Jenkins job properly?

Comment: Will be very hard to help you without seeing why the job failed. Please update your question to include logs of the failing job.

Answer (score 0):

Run your commands using `execute cmd/bash commands`. 
`Execute NodeJS script` expect a .js file to run just like `node index.js`.

`npm install` is not a valid nodejs script, it just a command for installing npm modules

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the issue.